# Do you get out of breath?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, spoken-english

I know what "*being out of breath*" and "*run out of something*" mean. So it should be OK to say "*I am out of breath*" and "*I usually run out of breath*". However, I am wondering if it is correct to say "*I get out of breath*". If that is correct, then can we use "*get out of breath*" instead of "*run out of breath*" (are they interchangeable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can describe your status as *I am X*, you can describe conditionally transitioning into that status with *I get X when Y* or similar.

> I am hot.
>
> I get hot when I wear too many clothes.
>
> I am out of breath.
>
> I get out of breath when I run too hard.

Answer (score 0):

> **out of breath**
>   :  breathing very rapidly (as from strenuous exercise)
>   [- M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out%20of%20breath)
>
> **out of breath** *phrase*
>   Gasping for air, typically after exercise.
>   ‘he arrived on the top floor out of breath’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/out_of_breath)

Consider also the following [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=out%20of%20breath%2Crun%20out%20of%20breath%2Cget%20out%20of%20breath&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20breath%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crun%20out%20of%20breath%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cget%20out%20of%20breath%3B%2Cc0):
[image: Out of breath Ngram]

The phrase "out of breath" is a *state*. As such, one can *be* out of breath, a situation that normally resolves with rest. Ngram's database records several instances of ***get*** out of breath, such as the following:

> 'Well, how often do you get out of breath in training?' I ask.
>   - [The Art of Running Faster](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=zaIOHHCB8qEC&pg=PA3&dq=%22get%20out%20of%20breath%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2983s74PWAhUFKJQKHb6QAMQQ6AEIMzAC#v=onepage&q=%22get%20out%20of%20breath%22&f=false) by Julian Goater, Don Melvin

Now, one can ***run*** out of breath, but that means something different - it means that one has no breath left. Here's an example, in which an initial quantity of air is inhaled, and when that quantity is fully exhaled, the person has *run out of breath*. It has nothing to do with gasping for air or strenuous exercise:

> Your pupils will discover that they are now having to think about their breathing as they are trying to expel all the air in their lungs by the end of the count to eight. One or two of them will run out of breath before you reach the number five – and a few will have timed it wrong, and have to blow out the last puff of air after you've finished speaking.
>   - [Making a Drama out of a Crisis](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=JRDfBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA68&dq=%22run%20out%20of%20breath%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZrZns74PWAhXCnZQKHUPHCR8Q6AEIODAE#v=onepage&q=%22run%20out%20of%20breath%22&f=false) by Tommy Donbavand